# iOS7 Autoresize When Switching Views Programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiviewcontroller

I have googled for a few hours with no luck, so I'm coming to you guys to save me here!

Apparently, I can't find the right information on how exactly to go about doing this (or the best way). I have an app that supports portrait and landscape (no support for upside down though). However, the portrait and landscape views are COMPLETELY different, so I'll need to use two views to represent each. Am I correct in assuming I need 3 viewcontrollers in my storyboard (the main one, and then one for portrait and one for landscape? I was going to use just two but I didn't see how to if I start with the portrait, and then need to load landscape, I would have to delete portrait, which is where my code is?

My viewcontroller has the correct constraints in place to keep the label top center, but when replacing or swapping the views programmatically, it seems the auto-resize doesn't get called. I finally fixed this by resetting the frames on the subviews, but now when the device is flipped upside down, the portrait label is forever shifted to the right. So I'd just like to know the proper way to do this, as I'm sure this can't be it.

As far as code, I have one obj-c viewcontroller class with the following modified methods...

```
@interface AMBViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *portraitViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *landscapeViewController;

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = app.statusBarOrientation;
    [self doLayoutForOrientation:currentOrientation];
}

-(void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:
(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self doLayoutForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

-(void) doLayoutForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)) {
        self.portraitViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Portrait"];

        if (self.landscapeViewController != nil ) {
            [self.landscapeViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            self.landscapeViewController = nil;
        }

        self.portraitViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view insertSubview:self.portraitViewController.view atIndex:0];
    } else {
        self.landscapeViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Landscape"];

        if (self.portraitViewController != nil ) {
            [self.portraitViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            self.portraitViewController = nil;
        }

        self.landscapeViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
        [self.view insertSubview:self.landscapeViewController.view atIndex:0];
    }

}
```

Just to be clear on my storyboard, I have one blank root controller (subclass AMBViewController) and two other view controllers "Landscape" and "Portrait"

I might also mention that the label only gets off in portrait view IF you rotate the device in a full circle (4 right or 4 left rotations). If you go right right (now it's upside down) but then left left, it's still fine. It's only when the screen flips from Right/Left Landscape to Left/Right Landscape that it messes up. Really weird, I know I must be omitting something important.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: After finding a guide located on [Apple's Dev Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH7-SW14) (finally) I was able to come up with a solution using segues and a modal window. First view controller is portrait, second view controller is landscape, connected by a modal segue. The first view controller has the following modified methods:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    _isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) && _isShowingLandscapeView
        && orientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        _isShowingLandscapeView = NO;

    } else if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && !_isShowingLandscapeView ) {

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLandscape" sender:self];
        _isShowingLandscapeView = YES;

    }
}
```

Thanks to all who might have looked into this!